# load dynamic lib several times into multiple independent scopes

Tags: macos, dll, shared-libraries, readline, dlopen

I want to dynamically load a library multiple times into independent scopes, so that each instance has its own memory. Is that possible?

I guess not in a portable way. Is it possible with `dlopen` and friends on POSIX/Unix/Linux? Or at least I care about MacOSX for my specific case right now (whereby I might need it later on other systems, too).

---

Background: The lib I want to use was not designed to be multithreading safe. However, it should work fine if each thread just uses an independent instance of the lib.

More background: It is the `readline` lib. Adding multithreading support there basically would mean to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: `readline` will be making use of the standard input, correct? Since this is not thread safe (as in supporting any kind of sane simultaneous use), you will not be able to use `readline` from multiple threads anyway.

Comment: @Dark Falcon: You can specify to `readline` where you want to read/write from/to. That's `rl_input`/`rl_output` (or so).

Answer (score 1):

> so that each instance has its own memory.

Depends on what you mean by "its own memory". Obviously, with POSIX threads, all memory is shared, so an instance of the library can not have "its own memory".

What you probably meant though is "so that each instance has its own copy of global variables", to which the answer is yes: see [dlmopen(3) docs](http://www.s-gms.ms.edus.si/cgi-bin/man-cgi?dlmopen+3DL). You'll want to pass `LM_ID_NEWLM` to it.

*Beware*: this is Linux and Solaris only, and GDB doesn't know anything about libraries loaded into non-default linker space, so debugging problems is currently very hard.

Comment: Yes, this is what I searched for. Unfortunately, I am searching for a way to do this on MacOSX.